# Lie-Transformation Lines to Spheres

Tags: geometry

In 3-dimensional space there are 4 degrees of freedom for straight lines and also for spheres (3 coordinates for its centre, 1 for its radius). I assume both sets are 4-manifolds. It is mentioned in a book that there is a transformation by Lie from lines to spheres involving complex numbers, but without further details. How is this transformation done?

Comment: Which book are you refering to?

Comment: Does the Wikipedia [Lie shpere geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_sphere_geometry) article have the details you need?

Comment: Thanks Somos! How do I declare that my question is answered?
@miraunpajaro: the book is Locher-Ernst: Geometrische Metamorphosen